# using Android Studio compiled the AES code to run SIGBUS (SIGBUS: illegal alignment)

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I use the eclipse compiler to run no problem, but the use of Android studio compiler will appear to access the alignment error

```
#define Te1 (u32)((u64*)((u8*)Te+3))

static const u64 Te[256] = {
    U64(0xa56363c6a56363c6), U64(0x847c7cf8847c7cf8),
    U64(0x997777ee997777ee), U64(0x8d7b7bf68d7b7bf6),
    U64(0x0df2f2ff0df2f2ff), U64(0xbd6b6bd6bd6b6bd6),
    ............};

u32 index = s1 >> 8 & 0xff; // 75
Te1[index]; // SIGBUS (SIGBUS: illegal alignment)
```

Comment: What is this?  C?  C++?  What are `u64`, `u32`, and `u8`?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i use the c ,                                                                                               typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned short u16;
typedef unsigned char u8;